# Getting null, when i make a external post endpoint using Spring webclient

Tags: spring, spring-webclient

Getting a null when i make call to post endpoint using spring webclient

I tried using webclient post end point. Got null instead og Object as return type

```
final int size = 16 * 1024 * 1024;
    
    final ExchangeStrategies strategies = ExchangeStrategies.builder()
            .codecs(codecs -> codecs.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(size))
            .build();
    
    

    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient() { 
        
        return WebClient
                .builder()
                .exchangeStrategies(strategies)
                .build();
    }
```

```
Object = countryz = webClient.post()
                .uri(new URI("https://countriesnow.space/api/v0.1/countries/population"))
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(country))
                .retrieve().bodyToMono(Object.class).block();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create Weblcient Bean

```
@Bean
public WebClient webClient() {
    final int size = 16 * 1024 * 1024;
    final ExchangeStrategies strategies = ExchangeStrategies.builder()
            .codecs(codecs -> codecs.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(size))
            .build();

    return WebClient.builder()
            .exchangeStrategies(strategies)
            .build();
}
```

2. In your service class

```
@Autowired
private WebClient webClient;


Object countryz = webClient.post()
                .uri("https://countriesnow.space/api/v0.1/countries/population")
                .header("cache-control", "no-cache")
                .header("content-type", "application/json")
                .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(Collections.singletonMap("country", "nigeria")))
                .retrieve().bodyToMono(Object.class).block();
```

Comment: Object countryz = webClient.post()
                .uri("https://countriesnow.space/api/v0.1/countries/population")
                .header("cache-control", "no-cache")
                .header("content-type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .header("postman-token", "4717afb5-f831-5eb1-f14d-74c987fa2ddb")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(Collections.singletonMap("country", "nigeria")))
                .retrieve().bodyToMono(Object.class).block();

Comment: I tried as per your suggestion. Still I am getting null. I hitted from post man. It comes to my controller to service log.info("Response from API:- {}", countryz);

Comment: 'curl --location --request POST 'https://countriesnow.space/api/v0.1/countries/population' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
 "country": "nigeria"
}'

Comment: Above one is external endpoint curl which has a data

Comment: 'String url = "https://countriesnow.space/api/v0.1/countries/population";
  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
  headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
  
  HttpEntity httpEntity = new HttpEntity(country, headers);
  RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

  ResponseEntity<Object> exchange = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, Object.class);
  log.info("Response from API:- {}", exchange.getBody());'

Comment: For the rest templates also, I am getting null. Is there any other sample post external endpoint API?

Comment: I'll come back to you with github reference working code

Comment: It seems the problem is with the external site. The code looks good. thanks for your time and help